# Change Object Key

Tags: object, key, crossfilter

This is my code so far (using crossfilter.js)...

```
function getCount(){
votersByDMA = voter_data.dimension(function(d) {if (d.dma === 'Burlington-Plattsburgh'){return 1} else {return 0}});
votersInDMA = votersByDMA.group().reduceCount();
voterCount = votersInDMA.all()[0].value;
console.log(votersInDMA.all());
console.log('value:' + voterCount);
```

}

and it console.logs this

```
0: Object
key: 0
value: 2
__proto__
1: Object
key: 1
value: 10406
```

I want to change the key so it takes the dma property of the data so it console.logs like this

```
0: Object
key: Madison, WI
value: 2
__proto__
1: Object
key: Burlington, VT-Plattsburgh, NY
value: 10406
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just change your dimension accessor to return the string instead of a number?

```
var votersByDMA = voter_data.dimension(function(d) {
   return d.dma;
});
```

Or, if you want to guarantee two buckets, `'Burlington-Plattsburgh'` and `'Other'`:

```
var votersByDMA = voter_data.dimension(function(d) {
   return d.dma === 'Burlington-Plattsburgh' ?
       d.dma : 'Other';
});
```

Comment: the data I'm using has many different DMAs, what I'm trying to do is use crossfilter to group the dataset by DMA name and then get the count of each. So the key should be the dma name and the value should be the count
so it looks like....
Object 0:
key: Madison, WI
value: 123

Object 1:
key: Burlington, VT-Plattsburgh, NY
value: 333

Object 3:
key: Roanoke, VA
value: 555

etc

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for putting me on the right track!

I did this.....
votersByDMA = voter_data.dimension(function(d) {if (d.dma_name){return d.dma_name} else {return 0}});